# Magento2 : Add new phtml file in Shipping Section of checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

I am working on custom extension and want to add phtml file code in shipping section of Magento2 at checkout process.
Can anybody help me with it?
See Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?